# I want to get OTP from request object header. please let me know that i am doing right or wrong

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets

```
public ResponseEntity<?> validatePayment(@PathVariable String paymentService,@PathVariable String invoicenumber,HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {           
        String otp = request.getHeader(otp);
        if(otp == null)
        {
                return ResponseEntityMapper.toResponseEntity("Please enter OTP" ,HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
                Payments response = paymentsServices.validatePayment(paymentService,invoicenumber,otp);
                return ResponseEntityMapper.toResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return ResponseEntityMapper.toResponseEntity(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
          }
        }
```

Comment: Greetings, welcome to SO! Could you please include your question in your post? Please check https://stackoverflow.com/tour on how to write a question, and try to improve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you need to *assign* the result of the `getHeader` to your variable.
e.g.

```
public ResponseEntity<?> validatePayment(@PathVariable String paymentService, @PathVariable String invoicenumber, HttpServletRequest request) {
try {           
    String otp = request.getHeader(<the name of your header goes here>)
    if (otp == null)
```

Comment: From where i will check the name of the Header

Comment: Are you saying you don't know what the name of the request header is?

Comment: So is OTP an acronym for One Time Password? You'll need to know the name of the header that the OTP value is passed by so that you can read it out. Headers are just a key/value store. If you don't know the key, how you going to get the value? You can use `request.getHeaderNames()` and log out all the values returned to get an idea of what you have to play with.